# Using GitHub: CLI vs IntelliJ GUI

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, command-line-interface

I am starting on project with a friend and this will be the first time either of us has worked in a collaboration. We both work in IntelliJ, neither of us has much experience with GitHub. My question is this, my partner refuses to set up GitHub in IntelliJ as he finds the GUI too unfamiliar and would prefer to do all GitHub requests via the command line while I prefer to do it all through IntelliJ GUI. I know that in IntelliJ I can see files color coded based on the various states while my partner can not.
Does anyone have experience with this? Should we both be using GitHub the same way or is the way we are doing it fine. I'm anticipating issues by us having different methods but honestly don't know enough to know if I am being overly anxious of problems or have valid concerns.

Comment: It does not matter at all.

Comment: This question may be too subjective for this site. But well... I have a colleague who uses git with IntelliJ and he runs frequently into problems. I'm pretty sure that if you know what you're doing, you can do anything but a lot of the time I just don't understand what's going on as things differ quite a lot from the CLI (what I prefer) rendering me unable to help.

Comment: What's confusing me is that he says his files within IntJ are not color coded after using the CLI while Mine are. I can glance at my IDE and know the various states of files at a glance while he can not. That seems like a potential issue.

Comment: It is his problem. He could enable VCS integration but use CLI for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tool you use to handle your git repository doesn't affect your collaborator's workflow - as long as your tool and the server properly behave.

Multi-language IDEs like IntelliJ tend to have some configurations for each project to know if, ie, git capabilities are enabled for that project or not. If your IDE is colouring files to tell you their git status, then you have those capabilities enabled. If your teammate's isn't, he has them disabled. That's all.

You probably are not versioning those IDE specific configurations, so that's why you have different settings. But that's no problem at all for collaboration.

Comment: Thanks, that was insightful. I think the issue is that my friend is making his repo the same folder as his project and he's not using Git properly at all. I've sent him off to learn more about Git before we progress.

Comment: I don't think this is a problem at all. He just has the IDE's git integration disabled, so he doesn't get git capabilities on his IDE - just as he asked. But using the git CLI he will be able to work without a problem.

Answer (score 3):

> my partner refuses to set up GitHub in IntelliJ as he finds the GUI too unfamiliar and would prefer to do all GitHub requests via the command line

I'd be the same way.

> Should we both be using GitHub the same way or is the way we are doing it fine.

Its fine to use different tools. Generally speaking, a single person should even be able to switch back and forth between using git CLI and a (competent) git GUI/IDE on their work dir at will throughout the day.

> Does anyone have experience with this?

I'm on a two-man team that uses git (but not GitHub - but that should not matter).  I use CLI on a Mac while my teammate uses TortoiseGit on Windows. (I think he also does some git stuff through Netbeans as well).  We had initially problems resolving the Mac vs Windows vs Unix issues (unrelated to CLI vs GUI), but we had no problems with accessing git using different UIs.

My biggest difficulty is explaining to my teammate how to do something complex like a complex rebase because of having to "translate" CLI commands into the TortoiseGit GUI menu items/dialog box options, especially if the UI is trying to be "helpful" by listing commands under "user-friendly" names rather than their git commands.

> neither of us has much experience with GitHub

[soapbox]

I think there's a real advantage in becoming proficient in the git CLI when just starting out with git.  I think that working with the CLI lays a good foundation of git knowledge and helps develop a good mental model of how git works. The GUIs, especially the ones in IDEs, tend to try to abstract/generalize the version control system (VCS) - trying to simplify the UI and be consistent across different VCSs. This is nice if you use several VCSs and/or don't need to learn the VCS very deeply, but its bad if you want to become a git guru.

After you get some proficiency in git and have a solid mental model of the git paradigm, then feel free to use a GUI - at that point you'll be mapping the GUI commands to your established mental model of git rather than trying to build a mental model of how git works from a diluted UI.

[/soapbox]

Answer (score 2):

If submitted code meets your agreed standard it is all that counts:)

Before using any tool (IDE), learn the material (CLI). It is invaluable for multiple reasons.

1. Forces you to learn WHAT it is and what it CAN do
2. Makes you to DO the steps necessary for YOUR work (omitting what you don't need)
3. Enables you to decide WHICH tool or procedure makes YOU more productive

If you're more productive with X, great! Share why it worked for you and let others to decide if it works for them. If you find yourself claiming that X is the best and others can submit faster - REEVALUATE. If you have to use tool X for whatever reason it will become your limitation (exception: the tool becomes de-facto standard).

If you see your untracked/new files in color, great for you! But maybe your partner does not care. Maybe he will once you show him `Ctrl + V (+4)`. Far more scary prospect is if both of you know only tool X.

With freedom comes responsibility.  With Git it is fairly simple because there is great community and excellent tutorials such as this at [Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials).

Comment: Thanks. I spent today drinking from the firehose. I just need to use it more to become comfortable with it. After viewing a video by Scott Chacon of GitHub I have a much better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think IDE is best at resolving merge conflicts and most commands. The most common issue occurs when people try to resolve merge conflicts /update the feature branch with parent master/develop branch. IDE sometimes confuses people with rebase vs merge decision. git command line clearly suggests use merge with rebase=false. Whereas iDE shows some buttons to merge / rebase and people just click something and see some unexpected behavior and lose faith.
[image]